# recursive method with nvelocity

Tags: castle-monorail, nvelocity

I'm working with monorail, I've :

in my model :

```
class Foo
{
   public List<Foo> foos;
}
```

in my controler :

```
PropertyBag["foos"] = foos; // foos is initialised
```

in my view :

```
<ul>
    #foreach($foo in $foos)
         <li>
            // recursive method I want to render alls the foos
         <li>  
    #end
</ul>
```

How can I do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try writing a recursive macro (see [caveats](http://www.castleproject.org/others/nvelocity/problems.html#macros), [reference](http://velocity.apache.org/engine/releases/velocity-1.5/user-guide.html#velocimacros), [example](http://old.nabble.com/recursion-list-of-lists-td25347148.html)), but I'd probably just write a [helper](http://www.castleproject.org/monorail/documentation/trunk/helpers/index.html) instead.

Comment: ok I tried with macro but I can't make it work, I will use Helper, Thank you